# Bot framework - generating directline token from my app service directline api not working

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I have created a bot(c#) and trying to connect it to webchat using directline. I referred this [here](https://github.com/leoalfa10/direct/tree/53cbf2c018442d9c0c925c55548b5153add2679c/samples/05.custom-components/j.typing-indicator) github repo and trying to connect my bot to webchat using directline token. but this directline extension >https://myappservicename.azurewebsites.net/directline/token won't generate any token if i send a post request. As in the HTML code given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-webchat-client?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) if I send the Post request with authorization header as bearer and my directline key im able to generate the token (in Postman) , but unable to connect to my bot in webchat. As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-net-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) I have configured the directline also. Any clarification would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable enhanced authentication options present in Channels > Directline > Your Website option. The problem is that directline isn't able to trust your origin to issue token as a result you aren't able to get the token.

[Here is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1OJa.png)